# Controling HDFS Replication ,mappers number and Reducers identification

Tags: apache, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run Apache Hadoop 2.65 in a distributed way (with a cluster of 3 computers) and I want to decide the number of mappers and reducers.
I am using HDFS with number of replication 1 and my input is 3 files (tables).
I want to adjust the way data flows in the system and for that, I would like to get some help with the following manners by is it possible? and how and where can I change it?

1. **Replication of HDFS**- Can I interfere with the way the replication of HDFS has been done? for example, make sure that each
   file stored in a different computer? and if so can I choose on which
   computer it will be stored?
2. **Number of mappers**-  Can I change the number of mappers or input splits?  I know that it is decided by the number of input splits and block size. It said on the web that I can do that by changing the following parameters but I don't know where?

   - -D mapred.map.tasks=5
   - mapred.min.split.size property
3. **Reducers identification**- How can I suggest or force the Resource manager to start the reduce containers (reduce tasks) on specific computers? and if so can I select their amount for each computer? (divide the map out output differently across the cluster). More specifically, add another parameter to the  ContainerLaunchContext (we have Mem, CPU, Disk, and Locality).

Answer (score 1):

Replication of HDFS- Can I interfere with the way the replication of HDFS has been done? 
Ans- Yes we can change replication factor in hdfs. just go config file change there.
Number of mappers- Can I change the number of mappers or input splits?

Ans - We can change number of mappers also in hdfs.

Comment: How can we change the number of mappers also in HDFS?
Do you mean like there is a parameter which I can edit in hdfs-site.xml that identifies the list of Datanodes that could have Map containers (be a mappers)?